# Can't port forward for a simple Python server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

I started working on a simple server and client script. I tested the script on my local network, and it worked great: The server would turn on, and wait for a client connection. As soon as a client connected, it would then let me proceed.

I then decided to test it over the internet, and this is were the problems start happening. I am running the server on Ubuntu, and the client on a windows machine.

Server Connection Code:

```
import socket
import sys

#Create a socket for connection
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''
        port = 5698
        s = socket.socket()
        print("Socket created.")
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))

#Bind the created socket to a port, sleep for conn
def socket_bind():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        s.bind((host, port))
        print("Waiting for connection")
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("SOcket binding error: " + str(msg) + "\n Retrying...")
        socket_bind()

#Estabilish Connection with client
def socket_accept():
    conn, adress = s.accept()
    print("Connection has been estabilished | " + "IP " + adress[0] + " | Port " + str(adress[1]))
    send_command(conn)
    conn.close()
```

Client Connection Code:

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess


# Create a socket
def socket_create():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = 'My Internet IP'
        port = 5987
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))


# Connect to a remote socket
def socket_connect():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        s.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket connection error: " + str(msg))
```

And the error:

> [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I'll never get the "Connection has been estabilished" print from the server, and I'll get that error.

Can anyone see anything that might be causing the problem in the code?

After port forwarding the router, do I have to do any other configs on Ubuntu itself? The ports I should open are as TCP, right?

After opening the port on the router, and if I use a service like "http://www.canyouseeme.org/", will it show instantly that the port is open, or will it only show if I'm running the server and waiting for a connection?

Comment: You should answer your own question with the solution you found. Others might run into the same issue.

Comment: @Malt I updated the question with a small description on the fix. I'll properly answer the thread with a small tutorial on how to use Port Mapper once i have time.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem. Here is an in-depth guide on how I did it.

The problem: Even after opening a port on your Router configs, you still can't see the port open on your running service.

The solution: Port Mapper.

Things to note: I had to run Port Mapper on Ubuntu, because running it on Windows didn't seem to work for me. Also, if you let your computer sleep or shutdown, when you turn it on again, you'll have to reopen the ports (but don't worry, as it is just a click of a button).

What you'll need: https://sourceforge.net/projects/upnp-portmapper/

- First, simply run 'java' in the terminal to make sure you have Java  installed, or in order to install it (directions will appear on screen).
- From the given link, download the Portmapper.jar.
- After downloading it, simply run 'java -jar Portmapper.jar' on the terminal to open up the gui.
- After opening the gui, press Connect so you can automatically connect to the router.
- All the current open ports will now appear on screen. We know want to look for the port mapping presets.
- In the Port mapping presets, go ahead and press Create.
- Here, give the preset a name. Then, fill the Remote Host if you want the connection of a specific IP, or leave it empty for any IP. The internal client will be your Server's network IP (in my case, because I'm running the server in the same machine as the Port mapper, I'll tick Use Local Host.
- Now we'll go ahead and add a new port as a TCP connection. Here we can either have the external and internal ports with equal or different values. Just remember the internal port (your machine's port) will be the one you'll use on your server, and the external port (your router open port) will be the one you'll use on your clients or whatever you are connecting to your server.
- After this, simply save the preset, choose it and press Use. If you know click Update under the ports list, you'll see your new open port. Just to make sure, you can get your server running awating connections, and simply go to "http://www.canyouseeme.org/", input the port, and here you go.
- Do remember that after shutting down or putting the computer asleep, you'll have to go back to PortMapper, and click Use on the preset you want again (depending on what port you want).